# Verify method calls on items in a collection with Moq

Tags: moq

My problem is NOT trying to simply verify whether a method was called or not.  Instead, I have a method that works on a collection of objects and I want to verify that a method on all of the collection items is being called.

Use the example of a plug-in model where I have a plug-in manager that contains a collection of plug-in objects. Each plug-in subclasses the PlugIn abstract base class which exposes an abstract Initialize method.  In my test I want to make sure that Initialize is called on every plug-in regardless of whether one of them throws an exception (just part of a larger test suite).

My initial approach was to create a collection of mocked plug-ins, then configure the class under test (PlugInManager) to use the mocked objects. I then perform the test by calling PlugInManager.DoWork() which should iterate through the collection, calling DoWork() on each item.

The full test codes is as follows:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void MyTest()
{
    // ARRANGE
    var testParameter = new Something();

    var mockPlugIns = new Collection<Mock<PlugIn>>()
    {
        new Mock<PlugIn>(),
        new Mock<PlugIn>(),
        new Mock<PlugIn>()
    };

    var plugIns = new Collection<PlugIn>();

    foreach (var plugIn in mockPlugIns)
        plugIns.Add(plugIn.Object);

    var testManager = new PlugInManager()
    {
        PlugIns = plugIns
    };

    // ACT
    testManager.DoWork(testParameter);

    // ASSERT
    foreach (var mockPlugIn in mockPlugIns)
        mockPlugIn.Verify(plugin => plugin.DoWork(testParameter), Times.Once());

    // Also tried using It.IsAny<Something>()
}

public abstract class PlugIn
{
    abstract void DoWork(Something something);
}

public sealed class PlugInManager
{
    public IEnumerable<PlugIn> PlugIns { get; set; }

    public void DoWork(Something something)
    {
        foreach (var plugIn in PlugIns)
            plugIn.DoWork(something);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Verify fails for every item.

I've stepped through the code and see that it actually is working correctly and the Initialize method is being called on every item. When, then, is Verify failing???

**UPDATE #1**

I've updated the post to show the entire test method in one block.  I've also changed the method to require a parameter as is the case in my real code (now).

**UPDATE #2**

The error I receive when running the test is:

```
Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: plugin => plugin.DoWork(It.IsAny<Something>())
No setups configured.
No invocations performed.
```

As mentioned, when I step through the unit test I see that each of the plugins are actually being called. For some reason, however, Moq doesn't seem to be registering it or recognizing it.

<s>**UPDATE #3**</s>

After playing with the test code more, I discovered that I could make the test pass with a simple change.  The test passes if I replace the foreach loop in the middle of the method with the following:

```
plugIns.Add(mockPlugIns[0]);
plugIns.Add(mockPlugIns[1]);
plugIns.Add(mockPlugIns[2]);
```

I don't see how this is making a difference and would ultimately like to make the number of items dynamic so the tests aren't always testing the case when there are three, so using the foreach is really what I need.

Any ideas?

This is actually not true and upon further testing this morning, I find that everything is working fine with the original foreach loop.  I have no idea what changed but I tried many different variations late last night and while the code I have this morning looks just like what is posted, for whatever reason, the test is now passing!?!?!?!?

Comment: Can you provide the full test or a simplified version of it? Because your approach if fine, it should work. And I also created a repro with your code and it's green for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in LINQPad with Moq 4. The only thing I changed was adding the parentheses on `Times.Once()`.

```
void Main()
{
    var MockPlugIns = new Collection<Mock<PlugIn>>()
    {
        new Mock<PlugIn>(),
        new Mock<PlugIn>(),
        new Mock<PlugIn>()
    };

    var plugIns = new Collection<PlugIn>();

    foreach (var mockPlugIn in MockPlugIns)
        plugIns.Add(mockPlugIn.Object);

    var testManager = new PlugInManager()
    {
        PlugIns = plugIns
    };

    testManager.Initialize();

    foreach (var mockPlugIn in MockPlugIns)
        mockPlugIn.Verify(plugin => plugin.Initialize(), Times.Once());
}

public abstract class PlugIn
{
    public abstract void Initialize();
}

public class PlugInManager
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        foreach (var plugIn in PlugIns)
        {
            plugIn.Initialize();
        }
    }

    public Collection<PlugIn> PlugIns { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I ran your updated test code, and it passed given the following implementation:

```
public class PlugInManager
{
    public void DoWork(Something s)
    {
        foreach (var plugIn in PlugIns)
        {
            plugIn.DoWork(s);
        }
    }

    public Collection<PlugIn> PlugIns { get; set; }
}
```

It passed with or without the It.IsAny change you mentioned. One initial thought was that you might not have been passing the same instance of Something to the plug-ins, but It.IsAny would have resolved that.

In short, it appears that you are doing everything right in the tests. Perhaps the issue is in the actual implementation.

Please post your implementation of PlugInManager.DoWork and the **exact** error message you get when the test fails. Also, what version of Moq are you using?

**UPDATE**

I cut-and-pasted your code and tried it. I had to make one change: `abstract void DoWork` on `abstract class PlugIn` needs to be `public`. After making that change it compiles and the test passes. If I comment out the "ACT" portion of your test, it fails with the error message you saw (as I would expect).

Something is different in your project or environment. I'm running .NET 4 (not Mono) under Windows 64 with Moq 4.0. Everything you have posted is correct. I would suggest confirming that you're running the latest binary of Moq, checking your project references, and trying some very simple verification tests to insure that Moq is working.

Comment: Your implementation is basically it. I've updated the post with the code as well as the error I'm receiving.

Comment: Yea, the 'public' was a cut-and-paste error (I deleted too much off that line when reformating.  I am running VS 2010, .NET 4 under Windows 7 32-bit using Moq 4.  I have over 250 unit tests in the solution, most use Moq, and this is the only test that is giving me problems.  See my updates for my recent findings.

Comment: The line should be `plugIns.Add(mockPlugIns[0].Object);`. Other than that it should make no difference. At this point I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Yea, another type-o. Not my best series of posts! For whatever reason, somewhere in all of the variations I tried yesterday, something changed because the test, in its original form, is passing.  I appreciate the help. While not getting me there directly, you certainly helped guide me down the path!

Comment: I will repost if I am able to recreate the problem and ever figure out why it was failing in the first place.